# How to get the marker and click on google map application programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to click on the **circles** on a google map loaded for testing purpose. I found that google does not fire JSONP request until I click on the marker exactly but if I click on the space outside the layers (see below example site) extent google does nothing and I inspected this request in network tab of chrome debugger. My scenario is as below

**Problem:**

I want to click on a marker (circles) loaded on the google maps programmatically.

Example map is [here](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zTIhb4N6Cl_4.kWb41QDth86c&hl=en)

**What I tried so far:**

Firbug,Fiddler,GMap Api,Proxy, Chrome debugger

**My asking**

1. How google detects if i have exactly clicked on the markers(circles)
   and fires JSONP requests ***immediately and comes up with an info
   window*** but does nothing when clicked ***outside*** of the layers
   loaded.
2. How this exact click on the marker can be done programmatically.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the space outside the layers"?

Comment: Thanks, https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zTIhb4N6Cl_4.kWb41QDth86c&hl=en will load several points of various radius if you click on the circles some functions are executed and a XHR event occurs that gets data from google map server but if you click outside the circles  no XHR happens. In fact i want how can i click on all circles in the ViewPort programmeticaly.